# updatePickerInput doesn't display the choice when a type has only 1 choice

Tags: r, shiny

I am learning to use `pickerInput` in Shiny and so I created this app. I have 2 categories **Fruit** and **Vegetable**. **Fruit** has 2 meals **Apple** and **Orange** and **Vegetable** has 1 meal **Carrot**. I am trying to use `updatePickerInput` to update the choice on the second box when the appropriate type is selected in the first box.

Here is my app

```
library(shiny, quietly = T)         # Dashboard Framework
library(bs4Dash, quietly = T)       # Style Extension
library(shinyWidgets, quietly = T)  # Widgets Extension
library(flexdashboard, quietly = T) # UI Elements
library(dplyr, quietly = T)

type <- c('Fruit','Fruit','Vegetable','Fruit','Vegetable')
meal <- c("Apple","Orange","Carrot","Apple","Carrot")
df.sample <- data.frame(type,meal,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

picker_type<- pickerInput(
  inputId  = "picker_type",
  label    = NULL,
  choices  = sort(unique(df.sample$type)),
  selected = unique(df.sample$type),
  multiple = FALSE,
  options  = list(size = 10),
  width = "100%"
)

picker_meal <- pickerInput(
  inputId  = "picker_meal",
  label    = NULL,
  choices  = NULL,
  multiple = TRUE,
  options  = list(
    `actions-box` = TRUE,
    size = 10,
    `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),
  width = "100%"
)

ui = bs4DashPage(

  header = bs4DashNavbar(
    skin = "secondary",
    status = "secondary",
    border = FALSE
  ),
  
  sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(
    skin = "dark",
    status = "secondary",
    elevation = 3,
    
    bs4SidebarMenu(
      bs4SidebarMenuItem(
        text = "Item",
        tabName = "item")
    )),
  
  bs4DashBody(
    
    bs4TabItems(
      
      bs4TabItem(
        tabName = "item",
    
        fluidRow(
          bs4InfoBox(title = h6("Type"),
                     width = 3,
                     elevation = 2,
                     color = "secondary",
                     fill = TRUE,
                     gradient = TRUE,
                     picker_type),
          bs4InfoBox(title = h6("Meal"),
                     width = 3,
                     elevation = 2,
                     color = "secondary",
                     fill = TRUE,
                     gradient = TRUE,
                     picker_meal)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Server
server = function(session, input, output) {
  
  observe({
    print(input$picker_type)
    updatePickerInput(session = session, 
                      inputId = "picker_meal", 
                      label = NULL, 
                      choices = df.sample %>% 
                        filter(type == input$picker_type) %>%
                        select(meal) %>% 
                        unique())
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I select **Fruit**, I get the correct choices in the second box

[image]

But, when I select **Vegetable**, I don't see the choice, which is **Carrot**

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `select()` to `pull()`. Select was returning a single row single column dataframe instead of the actual value of "carrot".

This worked for me:

```
# Server
server = function(session, input, output) {
  
  observe({
    print(input$picker_type)
    updatePickerInput(session = session, 
                      inputId = "picker_meal", 
                      label = NULL, 
                      choices = df.sample %>% 
                        filter(type == input$picker_type) %>%
                        pull(meal) %>% 
                        unique())
  })
  
}
```

[image: carrots]